# Remove changes from one file in git

Tags: git, git-stash

For example, I start from a clean commit, make some changes to different files, then I want to remove changes I made from only one file. How do I do it?
I tried to do:

```
git stash -p train.py
```

But I've got the error:

```
fatal: subcommand wasn't specified; 'push' can't be assumed due to unexpected token 'train.py'
```

Comment: Do you wan't to remove the changes, or stash them? There is a big difference.

Comment: Just `git restore train.py` if the file you want to remove changes from is yet uncommitted. If the changes are in the last commit (which is unclear from your description) then go for Antonio's solution.

Comment: If you want to use `git stash`, the error has told you how to solve it. Use `git stash push -p train.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're getting that error is because `git stash push` (which `git stash -p` is an alias for), doesn't allow custom arguments in order to avoid unintended stashing.

From the documentation for [`git stash push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-push-p--patch-k--no-keep-index-u--include-untracked-a--all-q--quiet-m--messageltmessagegt--pathspec-from-fileltfilegt--pathspec-file-nul--ltpathspecgt82308203):

> For quickly making a snapshot, you can omit "push". In this mode, non-option arguments are not allowed to prevent a misspelled subcommand from making an unwanted stash entry. The two exceptions to this are `stash -p` which acts as alias for `stash push -p` and pathspec elements, which are allowed after a double hyphen `--` for disambiguation.

In your case, `train.py` is a [*pathspec*](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec), so you must separate it from the recognized options by adding a `--` like this:

```sh
git stash -p -- train.py
```

Alternatively, you can spell out the entire command, in which case you don't have to separate the path with a double dash:

```sh
git stash push -p train.py
```

Note that using a double dash `--` to clearly separate a [pathspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec) from a command's known options [is a convention](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_argument_disambiguation) used by all Git commands that accept paths.

Answer (score 0):

You should:

```sh
git rebase HEAD~1

# Change, by the editor just opened, the word pick into edit, save and exit
# Edit you file

git commit
```